# Puppeteer returning null on Facebook settings page

Tags: facebook, xpath, puppeteer

**Update**

The problem I am having is reproducible in Chrome without puppeteer. I can see the text in the browser but there is no way to access the data via the javascript console.

**Original**

facebook privacy settings page has options that are visible from the browser and I can inspect them. The problem is the values from document.querySelector are null.

[image]

Here's the url:
https://www.facebook.com/settings

Here's the code

```
const el = await page.$x(
          '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span[3]/div/div[2]'
        );
const v = await page.evaluate((div) => div.textContent, el[0]);
```

I've also tried by using JS Path

```
const v = await page.evaluate(
          () =>
            (<HTMLElement>(
              document.querySelector(
                '#u_fetchstream_2_4 > li:nth-child(1) > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > span.fbSettingsListItemContent.fcg > div > div._nlm.fwb'
              )
            )).innerText
        );
```

Always getting the following error:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

I've confirmed that the property is null UNTIL i right-click inspect any value on the page -- bot detection that still shows the page?!

Also tried using xpath in Chrome's console:

```
$x('//*[text()="Who can see your future posts?"]')
```

returns `[]`

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't want you to scrape them. And all the selectors that you are using may change any day or several times a day.

Comment: Understood. So is this a limitation of puppeteer?

Comment: hi @paragbaxi, for me both the longer XPath expression and the one with `text()` method works and gives back the elements on chrome console. Are you sure there isn't any difference between the one posted above and the one you are trying in your script? (e.g. a wrongly encoded character, or a typo in the `text()=` sentence? The strangest thing is that you get `Cannot read property 'innerText' of null` insted of `Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined` (`null` vs. `undefined`) as your error is about it is not in the DOM at all.

Comment: Thank you @theDavidBarton. I tried a different account in an incognito window (not in puppeteer). Still getting empty arrays for all three commands directly from js console.

Answer (score 2):

There is a high chance you are trying to open the URL in different viewport dimensions. This kind of problem happens in responsive websites where the selectors are very different than how you selected them in browser.

The easiest way is to disable the default 800x600 resolution and turn on the headful mode so you can see what is going and and probably why it's failinig.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({defaultViewport: null, headless: false});
```

As for unblocking, facebook and other big companies really don't want you to scrape them. So you need to use combination of good proxies, user agent and stay under the radar.

You can try the stealth plugin which will try some unblocking techniques.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
```

*Disclaimer: It's highly recommended to use a dummy account for facebook to avoid getting banned. They really does not like bots on their platform.*

Comment: Thanks. I am already using the Stealth plugin and am in headful mode. I'm also using a new resolution. The problem I am having is actually reproducible in Chrome without puppeteer. I can see the text in the browser but there is no way to access the data via the javascript console.